# Speed add comments to cells using array VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with almost in any cell a string with the following structure

```
XX~Message
```

The end results is to have the code (`XX`) as cell value and the Message as a comment. (code has not a fix length)

At the moment I use instr to identify the position for the ~ and loop every cell in the range adding the message as comment but this is very slow because I have 30.000 rows and 13 columns.

Is there a way I can copy the range in an array, apply the changes in the array, then copy the array back in the sheet?

Comment: Yes there is - what have you tried? Just send the range of cells into an array, and loop, no?

Comment: You may have noticed a theme with the answer to your questions - they're not getting answers and the one that has hasn't had any confirmation from you that it was correct or not.  Could you have a read of [ask] and [mcve] please.  You're likely to get more responses.

Comment: You can copy to an array, but you will still have to assign the comment of the cell 1 by 1 from the array. It will marginally quicker, but not the speed gains you are probably hoping for. Make sure you have `Application.Screenupdating` set to false  and turn calculations off as that will help dramatically